# (unity) Как реализовать доступ к бд(MySQL) (любым устройствам) с использованием open server

Tags: php, c#, unity3d

Я делаю проект в Unity и на данный момент делаю систему авторизации , я использую local host и сервер на нем и так - же использую базу данных(MySQL)Это выглядит так , я использую простой код для WebRequest

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class Autoriztion : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string url = "http://visualvision";
    public TMP_Text respText;
    public TMP_InputField UserName;
    public TMP_InputField Password;
    public void LogIn()
    {
        string ULogin = UserName.text;
        string UPassword = Password.text;
        StartCoroutine(SendRegister(ULogin, UPassword));
    }
    IEnumerator SendRegister(string ULogin, string UPassword)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Newusername", ULogin);
        form.AddField("Newpassword", UPassword);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form))
        {
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("Response " + responseText);
                respText.text = responseText.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A на open server я использую скрипт

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["UserNameForm"])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["UserNameForm"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["PasswordForm"]);
    //is it empty
    if($username != "" && $password != ""){
        //is this login already using
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM UsersData WHERE UserName = '$username'")) == 0){
        mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO UsersData (UserName, Password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
        echo "Reg Username is " . $username . " and Password is " . $password;
        }else{
            echo "username already using";
        }
    }else{
        echo "The Fields is Empty";
    }
}
?>
```

где config

```
<?php
    $dbname = "Userdb"; //"Userdb"
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname)
?>
```

Все это работает , НО ТОЛЬКО В unity редакторе (на пк )и в билде(на этом же пк), что собственно и логично , а теперь вопрос как это можно реализовать чтобы доступ к бд можно было получить с разных устройств(т.е авторизоваться с другого устройства)

Comment: Залить на хостинг с поддержкой PHP и нужной БД